# Spring MVC How to give default dates in GET HTTP Request in my controller method?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datetime, http-request-parameters

How to give start date as `System.currentTimeMillis()` for default value in the request param for my controller method? Since this is a variable (requires constant), is there any other way to set this as default value? Like this:

`@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false, defaultValue = System.currentTimeMillis() ) long startDate`

Comment: try `@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false, defaultValue = "#{System.currentTimeMillis()}" )`

Comment: ok this does not give an error but I need to test this end to end if it gives proper values. Thanks though.